# always permit selected parameters in strong parameters in rails 4.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to always allow a specfic paramter 'format' in strong parameters. i am currently using rails 4.0.8

it has been included in rails 4.1 [here is the link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L111)

Rails guide suggest that it is configurable

`config.action_controller.always_permitted_parameters =  %w( controller action format )`

i am trying to find a way around it in rails 4.0.8. can this be achieved with some monkeypatch?

Comment: Not sure but what if you try to allow these params in your `action_controller` and call it in before filter?

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade to Rails 4.1? Any particular reason?

Comment: have you tried creating an helper method and call that before_filter ? or if you want to do it hard coded way then you can use this https://github.com/grosser/strong_parameters/tree/rails2
 Just a small question what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have some api calls which injects 'format'=>'json' with other attributes in params eg.{"latitude"=>"12.23", "longitude"=>"22.00", "name"=>"Your Corner Bakery", "cuisine_type"=>"Bakery", "format"=>"json","action"=>"some_action","controller"=>"controller_name"}. so for using strong parameters i will have to skip "format" which is not a table attribute.